# determine if pole is inside unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, circles

i would like to know  how to determine  if  pole  of given function is inside  unit circle contour? for example let us take this  function

$f(z)=(i-1)/(z+i)$  and we have contour    $z=\gamma(t)=2e^{it}$   where $0\leq t\leq\pi$.it just a example,in this case pole is equal to  $z=-i$,but suppose that pole is equal to $z=a+b*i$,actual if we have circle  with some radius  and given point,we can calculate distance between center and this point and see if  this distance is less then radius and after this we can say is it this point inside,on boundary or outside of circle,but what abut unit circle?please help  me

Comment: You're asking how to find out whether a point is inside the unit circle? That's the same as finding out whether it is inside any other circle.

Comment: but  in any other circle we have  coordinates and we can calculate distants

Comment: What coordinates are you missing? By definition the unit circle has its center at $0$ and radius $1$.

Comment: if i get  point like $z=5$,what would be easily way to determine of this point is inside circle?

Comment: Compute the distance from the center of the circle and see if it is smaller than the radius or not.

Comment: Let $z = a + ib$ where $a$ and $b$ are real how do you calculate $|z|$? and what's the relationship between $|z|$ and a circle?

Comment: but coordinates  of pint we have not right?

Comment: $|z|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

Comment: if this is less then $1$,then point is in unit circle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z = a + ib$ where $a$ and $b$ are real how do you calculate $|z|$? and what's the relationship between $|z|$ and a circle?

When we plot a complex point we plot with real part $a$ along the $x$ axis and the imaginary part $b$ on the $y$ axis. We therefore have the coordinates of a point.

We know that $|z| = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ so if $|z| \lt 1$ it's inside the unit circle.

Comment: if $z=5$,then $a=5$ and $b=0$ right

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: i wanted to make sure about this